# How to get Number Long value from the document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose-long` to create `NumberLong` type for the model, it works fine. But how can I get the value of the property with type `NumberLong`?
This is what I'm getting when accessing `NumberLong` property from the document `Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 869634269, high_: 373 },`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call methods on the returned `Long`, such as `toString()`, `toNumber()`, etc.

`http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html`